# Why run gts --shards not working for 2 or more devices in Android from perl or Python script

Tags: java, android, python, linux, cts

In Android `gts-tradefed` or `xts-tradefed`, the "shards" option from perl or Python script is not working for 2 or more devices.

### Python code

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('./gts-tradefed run gts --shards 2', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

### Output from command:

```
Android GTS 3.0_r5 build:3028956
Non-interactive mode: Running initial command then exiting.
Using commandline arguments as starting command: [run, xts, --plan, XTS, --shards, 2]
08-16 16:07:44 I/DeviceManager: Detected new device 100fb56f
08-16 16:07:44 I/DeviceManager: Detected new device 20bf34cc
08-16 16:07:44 I/unknown_device: Created result dir 2016.08.16_16.07.44
Saved log to /tmp/tradefed_global_log_6249175650313503897.txt
08-16 16:07:45 I/CommandScheduler: All done
```

If command `"run gts --shards 2"` is entered in `gts-tradefed` will work as expected.

Please suggest how to invoke `"./gts-tradefed run gts --shards 2"` and execute it from a Python or perl script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure try with

```
subprocess.check_output('./gts-tradefed run gts --shards 2',shell=True)
(or) subprocess.call('./gts-tradefed run gts --shards 2',shell=True)
```